# Stay focused on validation error with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have small application where I have a textbox bound to a model via MVVM:

My Model:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _myValue = 0;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public double MyValue 
    {
        get => _myValue;
        set
        {
            if(value != _myValue)
            {
                if (value == 4)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                _myValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a property was changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the affected property.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My View looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ValidationTests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ValidationTests"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="201.696" Width="322.679">
    
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding MyValue, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Content="Test"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now I want to keep the focus on the textbox when a validation error occurs. How can I achieve this? Is this possible with a style?

[image]

Comment: Look into implementing the `IDataErrorInfo` interface to handle these things; why throw `InvalidOperationException` on a wrong value, handle them gracefully.

Comment: Throwing exceptions in property setters for validation reasons is [perfectly fine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the keyboard focus from getting lost until the `TextBox` contains a valid value, you could handle the `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` event, either using an attached behaviour or directly in the view:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e) =>
    e.Handled = Validation.GetHasError((TextBox)sender);
```

You should also set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` to perform the validation before the focus gets lost:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center"
         PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus"/>
```

You cannot implement this in pure XAML, using a `Style` or something else.